# How to copy file from Ubuntu computer to remote box via SSH?

Tags: 16.04, ssh, transfer, scp

How to copy files from Ubuntu computer to remote box via SSH using **SecureCRT** utility? So I'm connected to media box via SSH, then `cd` to target folder: next how to copy file from computer into the `.config` folder on media box?

```
# pwd
/storage
# cd .config
```

Tried command but not work:

```
scp /path/to/file/on/local/computer/file.conf  root@192.168.1.45:file.conf
```

Computer and media box connected via router by wifi.

**Edit:** well, I used another way to upload file, **VanDyke SecureFX** tool, and it works fine:

```
SecureFX > File > Manual Upload > From:/To: > browse file > set transfer mode > OK
```

Comment: You will need to be more informative than *"not work"*

Comment: Your description sounds as if you issue the `scp` command on the media box and not on your computer. Please tell _where_ you issue the command and _what error_ it outputs.

Comment: Yes, I issued scp command on media box, not on PC, that is my mistake.